# MapServer: Hide the Map parameter .map Path

Tags: string, apache, url, webbrowser-control, mapserver

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to hide the file path value of Query String MAP parameter available on a MapServer request as shown bellow:
http://192.168.15.150/mapserver?MAP=/data/config/map/nasaww.map&%20service=wms&version=1.3.0&CRS=CRS:84&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/jpeg&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=-170,-90,170,90&WIDTH=600&HEIGHT=600&LAYERS=BlueMarble-200407&STYLE=raster
I am trying two solutions:

1. Based on MapServer [Env Variables](https://www.mapserver.org/optimization/environment_variables.html#environment-variables) - However this solution hind the MAP variable or replace the MAP value for a variable. Not really what I am looking for.
2. Use the Apache mod_rewrite as shown [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128964/htaccess-to-redirect-url-with-specific-query-string-to-a-different-domain-mai). I have configured my Virtualhost as shown bellow:

   > <Directory /data>
   > Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   > AllowOverride AuthConfig
   > Order allow,deny
   > Allow from all
   > RewriteEngine on
   > RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mapserver/?$
   > RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (^|&)MAP=([A-Z]*).map(&|$) [NC]
   > RewriteRule (.*)  http://192.168.15.150/wms?MAP=/data/config/map/%1  [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
   >
   > Alias /mapserver  /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mapserv
   > <location /mapserver>
   > setHandler cgi-script
   > Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
   > AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
   > Require all granted
   > SetEnv MY_PATH "/data/config/map/"
   > SetEnv MY_MAPFILE "/data/config/map/nasaww.map"

The Apache rewrite solution still did not work. Would anyone point me to any miss-configuration or give me some highlights to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2):

This is fully documented (by me, small world) on the official MapServer site, which gives several options for you to hide the `map=` parameter from the request: https://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html#changing-the-online-resource-url

That said, you might ask though 'which one do you recommend?', and here's my answer:

- for Linux: I use a wrapper script, which I always copy/paste from https://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html#wrapper-script-unix
- for Windows: I use a modification of that same method, but using the Apache `SetEnvIf` parameter in httpd.conf: https://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html#apache-setenvif

Let me know if that documentation needs any updates.  Thanks!  -jeff

Comment: Dear @mapserving, first of all, thank you very much for the precious documentation. I am glad I am talking to right person who wrote it. Sorry, but I still did not understand how I am going just type the request URL just passing the file.map to the MAP parameter and keep the file.map path hidden. If I set the env variable  SetEnv MY_MAPFILE "/data/config/map/file.map" I think it does the same thing as the wrapper script you mentioned. The request would be something like  /mapserv?MAP=MY_MAPFILE&... And that is fine. My point is how to change the request to .../mapserv?MAP=file.map&...

Comment: Would not be the case of using the https://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html#apache-rewrite-rules-using-apache-mod-rewrite? But this is something that I have been struggling with as well.

Comment: Please choose one of the two recommended methods mentioned above, depending on your operating system, and follow the example exactly.

Comment: Let me ask you one last thing regarding this topic, which directory should I place the wrapper script in an Ubuntu machine? The path to mapserv requires root permission.

Comment: @HelpOverFlow good question, it should live in your `/cgi-bin/` directory.  I've now updated the official documentation mentioned above, with this note.  Thanks!